# How to find the maximum of multiple 2D arrays in OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallelise this code:

```
        #pragma omp parallel for 
        for (i=0; i<=imax+1; i++) { // combined loops
            for (j=1; j<=jmax+1; j++) {
                umax = max(fabs(u[i][j]), umax);
                vmax = max(fabs(v[j][i]), vmax);
            }
        }
```

But there are race conditions for `umax` and `vmax`. Is there a way to fix this without serializing the code with `#pragma omp critical`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max value in an array using OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629261/max-value-in-an-array-using-openmp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to use the OpenMP reduction clause.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:umax, vmax)
    for (i=0; i<=imax+1; i++) { // combined loops
        for (j=1; j<=jmax+1; j++) {
            umax = max(fabs(u[i][j]), umax);
            vmax = max(fabs(v[j][i]), vmax);
        }
    }
```